# Leaving the Nest

Tags: code-golf, array

Given a non-flat list of integers, output a list of lists containing the integers in each nesting level, starting with the least-nested level, with the values in their original order in the input list when read left-to-right. If two or more lists are at the same nesting level in the input list, they should be combined into a single list in the output. The output should not contain any empty lists - nesting levels that contain only lists should be skipped entirely.

You may assume that the integers are all in the (inclusive) range `[-100, 100]`. There is no maximum length or nesting depth for the lists. There will be no empty lists in the input - every nesting level will contain at least one integer or list.

The input and output must be in your language's native list/array/enumerable/iterable/etc. format, or in any reasonable, unambiguous format if your language lacks a sequence type.

### Examples

```js
[1, 2, [3, [4, 5], 6, [7, [8], 9]]] => [[1, 2], [3, 6], [4, 5, 7, 9], [8]]

[3, 1, [12, [14, [18], 2], 1], [[4]], 5] => [[3, 1, 5], [12, 1], [14, 2, 4], [18]]

[2, 1, [[5]], 6] => [[2, 1, 6], [5]]

[[54, [43, 76, [[[-19]]]], 20], 12] => [[12], [54, 20], [43, 76], [-19]]

[[[50]], [[50]]] => [[50, 50]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pyth, 17

```
 us-GeaYsI#GQ)S#Y
```

The leading space is important. This filters the list on whether the values are invariant on the `s` function, then removes these values from the list and flatten it one level. The values are also stored in `Y` and when we print we remove the empty values by filtering if the sorted value of the list is truthy.

[Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=+us-GeaYsI%23GQ%29S%23Y&input=%5B1%2C+2%2C+%5B3%2C+%5B4%2C+5%5D%2C+6%2C+%5B7%2C+%5B8%5D%2C+9%5D%5D%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C+2%2C+%5B3%2C+%5B4%2C+5%5D%2C+6%2C+%5B7%2C+%5B8%5D%2C+9%5D%5D%5D%0A%5B3%2C+1%2C+%5B12%2C+%5B14%2C+%5B18%5D%2C+2%5D%2C+1%5D%2C+%5B%5B4%5D%5D%2C+5%5D%0A%5B2%2C+1%2C+%5B%5B5%5D%5D%2C+6%5D%0A%5B%5B54%2C+%5B43%2C+76%2C+%5B%5B%5B-19%5D%5D%5D%5D%2C+20%5D%2C+12%5D%0A%5B%5B%5B50%5D%5D%2C+%5B%5B50%5D%5D%5D&debug=0)

Alternatively, a 15 byte answer with a dubious output format:

```
 us-GpWJsI#GJQ)
```

[Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%20us-GpWJsI%23GJQ%29&input=%5B1%2C%202%2C%20%5B3%2C%20%5B4%2C%205%5D%2C%206%2C%20%5B7%2C%20%5B8%5D%2C%209%5D%5D%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C%202%2C%20%5B3%2C%20%5B4%2C%205%5D%2C%206%2C%20%5B7%2C%20%5B8%5D%2C%209%5D%5D%5D%0A%5B3%2C%201%2C%20%5B12%2C%20%5B14%2C%20%5B18%5D%2C%202%5D%2C%201%5D%2C%20%5B%5B4%5D%5D%2C%205%5D%0A%5B2%2C%201%2C%20%5B%5B5%5D%5D%2C%206%5D%0A%5B%5B54%2C%20%5B43%2C%2076%2C%20%5B%5B%5B-19%5D%5D%5D%5D%2C%2020%5D%2C%2012%5D%0A%5B%5B%5B50%5D%5D%2C%20%5B%5B50%5D%5D%5D&debug=0)

#### Expansion:

```
 us-GeaYsI#GQ)S#Y     ##   Q = eval(input)
 u          Q)        ##   reduce to fixed point, starting with G = Q
        sI#G          ##   get the values that are not lists from G
                      ##   this works because s<int> = <int> but s<list> = flatter list
      aY              ##   append the list of these values to Y
     e                ##   flatten the list
   -G                 ##   remove the values in the list from G
              S#Y     ##   remove empty lists from Y
```

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, <s>56</s> <s>54</s> 52 bytes

<sub>*-2 bytes due to [Alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9288).*</sub>

<sub>*-2 bytes due to [CatsAreFluffy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51443).*</sub>

```
Cases[#,_?AtomQ,{i}]~Table~{i,Depth@#}/.{}->Nothing&
```

Actually deletes empty levels.

Comment: `Cases[#,_?AtomQ,{i}]~Table~{i,Depth@#}~DeleteCases~{}&`

Comment: `Cases[#,_?AtomQ,{i}]~Table~{i,Depth@#}/.{}->Nothing&`, 2 bytes shorter

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 78 bytes

```py
f=lambda l:l and zip(*[[x]for x in l if[]>x])+f(sum([x for x in l if[]<x],[]))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica <s>55 64</s> 62 bytes

```
#~Select~AtomQ/.{}->Nothing&/@Table[Level[#,{k}],{k,Depth@#}]&
```

---

```
%&[{1, 2, {3, {4, 5}, 6, {7, {8}, 9}}}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, 6}, {4, 5, 7, 9}, {8}}

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 79

I *know* the Retina experts will golf this more, but here's a start:

```
{([^{}]+)}(,?)([^{}]*)
$3$2<$1>
)`[>}],?[<{]
,
(\d),+[<{]+
$1},{
<+
{
,*[>}]+
}
```

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=K2B7LD99CgooYHsoW157fV0rKX0oLD8pKFtee31dKikKJDMkMjwkMT4KKWBbPn1dLD9bPHtdCiwKKFxkKSwrWzx7XSsKJDF9LHsKPCsKewosKls-fV0rCn0&input=e3s1NCx7NDMsNzYse3t7LTE5LHt7fSx7e319fX19fX0sMjB9LDEyLHt7fX19)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>112</s> 80 bytes

```js
F=(a,b=[],c=0)=>a.map(d=>d!==+d?F(d,b,c+1):b[c]=[...b[c]||[],d])&&b.filter(d=>d)
```

Thanks Neil for helping shave off 32 bytes.

Comment: Lots of opportunities for golfing here. Some easy ones are to remove the `!=null` as `null` is falsy anyway. The `b=` is also unnecessary. Having removed that you can then move the `.filter(a=>x)` to the `&&b` which then reduces the outer function to a call to the inner function which you can then inline. I'm left with this: `f=(a,b=[],c=0)=>a.map(d=>d[0]?f(d,b,c+1):b[c]=[...b[c]||[],d])&&b.filter(d=>d)`.

Comment: @Neil `d[0]?` would evaluate `false` if it was equal to `0`, which is within the range `[-100,100]`. And so would `d=>d`

Comment: @Neil Threw this one up in a rush, so I knew there were other opportunities to shrink it, but this is much better than I could have done even then. Thanks! Oh, and Patrick is right on the null check being necessary for that reason. I went with `d===+d` though, since it saves 2 bytes on the null check.

Comment: `F=(a,b=[],c=0)=>(a.map(d=>d!==+d?F(d,b,c+1):b[c]=[...b[c]||[],d]),b)` for -12 bytes.

Comment: @Dendrobium That won't handle the last case (or any cases with `[...,[[...]]]`) properly

Comment: @PatrickRoberts `d=>d` is OK since `d` is always an array or null at that point, but a fair point regarding `d[0]`, although there's always `d.map` which will be truthy for an array but falsy for a number.

Answer (score 1):

## Jelly, 24 bytes

```
fFW®;©ṛ¹ḟF;/µŒḊ’$¡W®Tị¤;
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=ZkZXwq47wqnhuZvCueG4n0Y7L8K1xZLhuIrigJkkwqFXwq5U4buLwqQ7&input=&args=W1s1NCwgWzQzLCA3NiwgW1tbLTE5XV1dXSwgMjBdLCAxMl0)

If newline-separated lists were allowed, this could be golfed down to **14 bytes**.

```
fFṄ¹¹?ḟ@¹;/µ¹¿
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=ZkbhuYTCucK5P-G4n0DCuTsvwrXCucK_&input=&args=W1s1NCwgWzQzLCA3NiwgW1tbLTE5XV1dXSwgMjBdLCAxMl0)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ŒJẈĠịF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJK@HuzqOLHi4u9vt/@H2R01rjk56uHMGkI78/z/aUEfBSEch2hiITXQUTGN1FMyATHMgtgCyLWNjYyGyQHXRhiCVhiYgAiRpBMSGIOloE5AqkN5oI4jKaFOQiBlY0hSkwQRohDnI5OhoXUOQqSD9BiADjMCKok0NYiGqgXQsAA)

Jelly has [substantially improved](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/73659/66833) in the past 5 years

### How it works

```
ŒJẈĠịF - Main link. Takes a list L on the left
ŒJ     - Multi-dimensional indices
  Ẉ    - Get the length of each element
         This yields the depth (starting at 1 for flat elements) of each element
   Ġ   - Group the indices of this list by the values
     F - Flatten L
    ị  - Index into
```

Huh? The way that `ŒJẈĠ` works is kinda confusing without an example. Let's take `L = [3, 1, [12, [14, [18], 2], 1], [[4]], 5]` and work through it

`ŒJ` is one of a series of multi-dimensional commands that reflect the behaviour of their one-dimensional versions. Specifically, this is the "multi-dimensional indices" command, a multi-dimensional version of `J`, the "indices" command.

Picture `L` arranged like this:

```
3 1 12 14 18 2 1 4 5
    12 14 18 2 1 4
       14 18 2   4
          18
```

That is, each element is repeated down a number of times equal to it's depth. `ŒJ` doesn't quite leave the elements like this (it changes the specific values, not the shape), but it's enough. `Ẉ` then calculates the length of each i.e. how many rows each element goes down:

```
1 1 2 3 4 3 2 3 1
```

`Ġ` the takes this list as it's argument. First, it's generates this list's indices: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. We then group these indices by the values of the argument. So because the values at indices `3` and `7` are equal (they're both `2`), `[3, 7]` is grouped. The final result of this is `[[1, 2, 9], [3, 7], [4, 6, 8], [5]]` as the groups are sorted by the values they're grouped by.

Finally, we index into the flattened `L` using this list of groups, which yields the intended output

Answer (score 0):

## Python, <s>108</s> 99 bytes

This seems a bit long to me, but I couldn't make a one-liner shorter, and if I try using `or` instead of `if`, I get empty lists in the results.

```python
def f(L):
    o=[];i=[];j=[]
    for x in L:[i,j][[]<x]+=[x]
    if i:o+=[i]
    if j:o+=f(sum(j,[]))
    return o
```

[**Try it online**](http://ideone.com/FhIvyM)

Edit: [Saved 9 bytes thanks to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12135169/2415524)

Comment: You should change your indents to single spaces, so they render properly in the code block. You can also use `filter(None,o)` to remove empty lists that are on the outermost nesting level of `o`.

Comment: I prefer to view my code with tabs. Spaces are evil.

Comment: SE Markdown converts tabs to 4 spaces, so there's no escaping them anyway :) Using a single space in the Markdown makes the byte count of the code block actually match the byte count of the code.

Comment: My code itself contains tabs if you look to edit it, though. It's whats on the inside that counts. ;)

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 37 bytes

```
j']['!=dYsXKu"GK@=)'[\[\],]'32YXUn?1M
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=aiddWychPWRZc1hLdSJHS0A9KSdbXFtcXSxdJzMyWVhVbj8xTQ&input=W1s1NCwgWzQzLCA3NiwgW1tbLTE5XV1dXSwgMjBdLCAxMl0)

Works with [current release (13.0.0)](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/13.0.0) of the language/compiler.

This produces the output as lines of space-separated values, where each line corresponds to the same nesting level, and different nesting levels are separated by newlines.

```
j            % read input as string (row array of chars)
']['!        % 2x1 array containing ']'  and '['
=            % test for equality, all combinations
d            % row array obtained as first row minus second row
Ys           % cumulative sum. Each number is a nesting level
XK           % copy to clibdoard K
u            % unique values: all existing nesting levels
"            % for each nesting level
  G          %   push input
  K          %   push array that indicates nesting level of each input character
  @          %   push level corresponding to this iteration
  =          %   true for characters corresponding to that nesting level
  )          %   pick those characters
  '[\[\],]'  %   characters to be replaced
  32         %   space
  YX         %   regexp replacement
  U          %   only numbers and spaces remain: convert string to array of numbers
  n?         %   if non-empty
    1M       %     push that array of numbers again
             %   end if implicitly
             % end for each implicitly
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 3, 109 bytes

As ever, stupid Python 2 features like comparing `int`s and `list`s mean that Python 3 comes out behind. Oh well...

```py
def d(s):
 o=[]
 while s:
  l,*n=[],
  for i in s:
   try:n+=i
   except:l+=[i]
  if l:o+=[l]
  s=n
 return o
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 63 bytes

```
{$o[$x++]=[@t]if@t=grep{!ref}@i;(@i=map{@$_}grep{ref}@i)&&redo}
```

Input is expected in `@i`, output produced in `@o`. (I hope this is acceptable).

Example:

```
@i=[[54, [43, 76, [[[-19]]]], 20], 12];                              # input

{$o[$x++]=[@t]if@t=grep{!ref}@i;(@i=map{@$_}grep{ref}@i)&&redo}      # the snippet

use Data::Dumper;                                                    # print output
$Data::Dumper::Indent=0;  # keep everything on one line
$Data::Dumper::Terse=1;   # don't print $VAR =
print Dumper(\@o);
```

Output:

```
[[12],[54,20],[43,76],[-19]]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 119 bytes

**(116 with seq? and input as lists, a trivial modification)**

```
(defn f([v](vals(apply merge-with concat(sorted-map)(flatten(f 0 v)))))([l v](map #(if(number? %){l[%]}(f(inc l)%))v)))
```

Better intended:

```
(defn f([v]  (vals(apply merge-with concat(sorted-map)(flatten(f 0 v)))))
       ([l v](map #(if(number? %){l[%]}(f(inc l)%))v)))
```

When called with two arguments (the current level and a collection) it either creates an one-element unordered-map like `{level: value}`, or calls `f` recursively if a non-number (presumambly a collection) is seen.

These mini-maps are then merged into a single `sorted-map` and key collisions are handled by `concat` function. `vals` returns map's values from first level to the last.

If a number is the only one at its level then it remains a `vec`, others are converted to lists by `concat`.

```
(f [[54, [43, 76, [[[-19]]]], 20], 12])
([12] (54 20) (43 76) [-19])
```

If input was a `list` instead of `vec` then `number?` could be replaced by `seq?`, oddly vector isn't `seq?` but it is `sequential?`. But I'm too lazy to implement that version, re-do examples etc.

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 259 bytes

```
(let((ol'())(m 0))(let p((l l)(n 0))(cond[(empty? l)][(list?(car l))(set! m(+ 1 n))
(p(car l)(+ 1 n))(p(cdr l)n)][(set! ol(cons(list n(car l))ol))(p(cdr l)n )]))
(for/list((i(+ 1 m)))(flatten(map(λ(x)(cdr x))(filter(λ(x)(= i(list-ref x 0)))(reverse ol))))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f l)
  (define ol '())
  (define maxn 0)
  (let loop ((l l)              ; in this loop each item is added with its level
             (n 0))
    (cond
      [(empty? l)]
      [(list? (first l))
       (set! maxn (add1 n))
       (loop (first l) (add1 n))
       (loop (rest l) n)]
      [else
       (set! ol (cons (list n (first l)) ol))
       (loop (rest l) n )]))

  ; now ol is '((0 1) (0 2) (1 3) (2 4) (2 5) (1 6) (2 7) (3 8) (2 9)) 

  (for/list ((i (add1 maxn)))   ; here similar levels are combined
    (flatten
     (map (λ (x) (rest x))      ; level numbers are removed
          (filter (λ (x) (= i(list-ref x 0)))
                  (reverse ol))))))
```

Testing:

```
(f '[1 2 [3 [4 5] 6 [7 [8] 9]]])
```

Output:

```
'((1 2) (3 6) (4 5 7 9) (8))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
é╔óó)₧ú↔u.≤∟╦Ç╟·○`
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=82c9a2a2299ea31d752ef31ccb80c7fa0960&i=%5B1,+2,+%5B3,+%5B4,+5%5D,+6,+%5B7,+%5B8%5D,+9%5D%5D%5D%0A%5B3,+1,+%5B12,+%5B14,+%5B18%5D,+2%5D,+1%5D,+%5B%5B4%5D%5D,+5%5D%0A%5B2,+1,+%5B%5B5%5D%5D,+6%5D%0A%5B%5B54,+%5B43,+76,+%5B%5B%5B-19%5D%5D%5D%5D,+20%5D,+12%5D%0A%5B%5B%5B50%5D%5D,+%5B%5B50%5D%5D%5D&m=2)

I rhought I'd be able to beat pyth, but ¯\_(○-○)_/¯